# Spotify ios sdk suddenly failing on all requestItemAtURI

Tags: ios, spotify

```
requestItemAtURI received error
Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk Code=101
"JSON object contains no URI" UserInfo=0x16e2e890 
{NSLocalizedDescription=JSON object contains no URI}
```

Testing with various uri have previously succeeded until just now, for example, this uri should be valid:

```
spotify:track:5jSz894ljfWE0IcHBSM39i
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is part of the "This SDK may stop working at any time" part of the Beta. There'll be an update before long to resolve it.

Comment: So what would you recommend to someone starting today an iOS app that requires Spotify? Wait for the new SDK or use the old Cocoalibspotify? Is there an ETA?

Comment: Even if it was working, the iOS SDK is in beta and isn't appropriate for writing applications you intend to ship at the moment.